# Validación de Schemas para el manejo de longitud de strings

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo el siguiente modelo en `mongoose`

```
import mongos from 'mongoose'
import validator from 'mongoose-unique-validator'

const schema = new mongos.Schema({

    name: { 
        type     : String, 
        required : [ true, 'El nombre del rol es necesario' ],
        unique   : [ true, 'Ya existe un rol con ese nombre' ],
        max      : [ 50, 'El nombre no puede exceder los 50 caracteres' ],
        min      : [ 3, 'El rol debe contener 3 o más caracteres' ]
    },
    status       : { type: String, default: 'active' },
    addedBy      : { type: mongos.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    addedDate    : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    modification : {
        user     : { type: mongos.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        date     : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        current  : { type: String },
        updated  : { type: String }
    }
}, { collection: 'roles' } )


schema.plugin( validator, { message: 'Ya existe {VALUE} en la base de datos' } )

const RoleModel = mongos.model( 'Role', schema )

export default RoleModel
```

Cuando inicio las validaciones:

1. Pasó el `required`
2. Pasó el `unique`
3. No pasó el `max` (Hace la inserción)
4. No pasó el `min` (Hace la inserción)

No entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, me podrían apoyar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema está en que usas la validación inadecuada para el tipo de campo que deseas validar.

Las [validaciones incorporadas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html##%7Bblock.identifier%7D) de Mongoose [`min` y `max`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#number-validators) son validaciones usadas para datos tipos [`Number`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#numbers), y tu deseas validar datos tipo [`String`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#strings).

Las validaciones que debes usar para un tipo `String` son [`minlength` y `maxlength`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#string-validators).

Tu esquema de Mongoose debería ser así:

```
import mongos from 'mongoose'
import validator from 'mongoose-unique-validator'

const schema = new mongos.Schema({

    name: { 
        type           : String, 
        required       : [ true, 'El nombre del rol es necesario' ],
        unique         : [ true, 'Ya existe un rol con ese nombre' ],
        maxlength      : [ 50, 'El nombre no puede exceder los 50 caracteres' ],
        minlength      : [ 3, 'El rol debe contener 3 o más caracteres' ]
    },
    status       : { type: String, default: 'active' },
    addedBy      : { type: mongos.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    addedDate    : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    modification : {
        user     : { type: mongos.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        date     : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        current  : { type: String },
        updated  : { type: String }
    }
}, { collection: 'roles' } )


schema.plugin( validator, { message: 'Ya existe {VALUE} en la base de datos' } )

const RoleModel = mongos.model( 'Role', schema )

export default RoleModel
```

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.